# Why Ajax Jquery form click not working vs div that works?

Tags: ajax, json, html, forms

Ajax Jquery form not working vs div why its happen and how can i fix my error?

**view.html-Code with form**

### not working

```
<html>
    <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="parse-form" action="#" method="post">
            <button type="submit" id="submit-html">submit ajax request without parameters</button>
        </form>
        <div>array values: <div id="array-values"></div></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#submit-html').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'controller.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("response begin");
                            alert(data);
                            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                                $('#array-values').append('<div>'+elem+'</div>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**view.html -form replaced by div**

### working

```
<html>
    <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parse-form">
            <button type="submit" id="submit-html">submit ajax request without parameters</button>
        </div>
        <div>array values: <div id="array-values"></div></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#submit-html').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'controller.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert("response begin");
                            alert(data);
                            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                                $('#array-values').append('<div>'+elem+'</div>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**controller.php -simple php file that return json array:**

```
<?php
$arr=array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you're posting if there's no data, would a GET/`$.getJSON()` be an issue for any reason?  It would be a much simpler approach...or are you planning to `.serialize()` additional data other than the example?

Comment: I simplify the code, in real code i should send input text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form has a default action with a `type="submit"` button, which is submitting, so you'll need to stop that from happening by adding `return false` or [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) , like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-html').click(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("response begin");
                alert(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                    $('#array-values').append('<div>'+elem+'</div>');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
        //or e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Without this, the form is submitting as it normally would with no JavaScript, leaving the page.  So effectively it's doing a refresh, instead of AJAX submitting your form (which doesn't have time to complete...because you left :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `form` is submitting and refreshing the page before the ajax has a chance to respond.

Try putting `return false;` at the end of the `click` handler.

```
$('#submit-html').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'controller.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("response begin");
      alert(data);
      $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
        $('#array-values').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Of course you'll have the same issue if the user hits `Enter` in one of the fields. Unless you're preventing the `Enter` key from submitting the form, you may want to the handle the event using the `submit()` handler.

```
$('#parse-form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'controller.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert("response begin");
      alert(data);
      $.each(data, function(i, elem) {
        $('#array-values').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An element of `type=submit` inside a `<form>` will perform the form request when clicked on.

You need to abort the default behavior by running `event.preventDefault()` inside the click callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try using submit() http://api.jquery.com/submit/ , this should work with keyboard events as well as clicks. You can use serialize() to get any form data into the ajax objects data variable.

Comment: its not works with submit, serialize() what? - I dont send any form data.